# undefined method `capture_haml' for #<#<Class:0xbe53d68>:0xcf9cb24> in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am working on deleting a branch of a company using `rails ajax`.

Simple form for company account is -

```
= simple_form_for @company_account, :remote => true,
                                :url =>  company_account_path,
                                :method => :put do |f|
```

using this form i am creating, updating and deleting regions and branches of regions.

```
%div{ :id => 'branches_' + r.id.to_s}= render 'branches',f: f, r: region, company_account: @company_account
```

relation between company, region and branch is:

```
company has_many: regions
region belong_to: company
regions has_many: branches
branches belongs_to: regions
```

In this form i have a partial for displaying regions and branches, which uses form object of company account `f`. All this is working fine. I'm able to create new regions branches. Now i'm trying to delete branch using `ajax`.

When this call goes to controller i'm creating a form object for company account to render a partial like - **In my controller**

```
@f = view_context.simple_form_for @company_account, :remote => true,
                                :url =>  company_account_path,
                                :method => :put do |f|
 render_to_string(:partial => 'company_accounts/branches', :locals => {f: f, r: @region, company_account: @company_account }).html_safe

end
```

and passing this @f object in responce using javascript as -

```
$('#branches_' + <%= @region.id%>).html('<%= escape_javascript @f %>');
$('#branches_' + <%= @region.id%>).show();
```

But unfortunately in response i am getting error -

```
undefined method `capture_haml' for #<#<Class:0xbe53d68>:0xcf9cb24>
```

Don't know what i am missing. Can any one please help??

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

This is the Backtrace:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `capture_haml' for #<#<Class:0xb9db2a4>:0xc953560>):
    1: #inactive_branches
    2:   = f.simple_fields_for :regions, r do |reg|
    3:     %table.preferenceDetails
    4:       %tr
    5:         %td
  app/views/company_accounts/_inactive_branches.html.haml:2:in `_app_views_company_accounts__inactive_branches_html_haml___356774371_104988750'
  app/controllers/company_accounts_controller.rb:129:in `block in branches'
  app/controllers/company_accounts_controller.rb:122:in `branches'
```

Comment: A backtrace would help a lot here. If you're not calling `capture_haml`, sounds like one of your helpers is, and in a context where it shouldn't be.

Comment: I did all backtrace, with no luck..:(

Comment: I think he means that you should post the backtrace that results from the `undefined method` that you're getting.

Comment: woh sorry.. updated my error log in question

Comment: I have solved this issue by another way.. But i want to see why this has caused and probable solution for this issue that will help others if cme across same problem.. So if any one answers in remaining 5 days, still i will accept the answers...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by another way.

I am rendering a main partial of regions, in which form for @company account is created. Then kept both active/inactive branches partials in `_regions.html.haml` adding a condition on it.

When page is loaded it shows active branches by default and on the basis of request sent to show inactive branches then inactive branches partial is rendered.